# __doPostBack does not work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an Exit button on the an aspx page that needs to execute some server side code and then close the browser window. The button has an OnClick event and an OnClientClick event. The OnClientClick event calls the method that will should do a postback and then close the window. The code works fine in IE but will not do the postback in Chrome. The window closes in both cases. Here is my code. I'm checking to see which browser it is, but not doing anything different in each case at this point

```
function closeMainWindow(control) {
            var clientIDName = control.name;
            if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') != -1) {
                __doPostBack(clientIDName, '');
                    window.open('', '_self', ''); //need this for Chrome
                    window.close();
                    return false;
            }
                else {
                __doPostBack(clientIDName, '');
                window.open('', '_self', ''); //bypasses warning from IE
                window.close();
                return false;
            }
```

Here is the code for the button.

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnExit" runat="server" Text="Yes" Width="50px" OnClick="btnExit_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:return closeMainWindow(this);" />
```

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to make this work in Chrome or if there is a better/different way to execute server side code and then close the browser window.

Comment: Is there any error in Chrome's Javascript console?

Comment: Am I missing something or is the logic not identical for Chrome vs. non-Chrome in your posted code?

Comment: I guess trying to close the window without being sure your POST request has been completely handled is a bad idea. If you don't want to implement some server side js like @YuriyGalanter suggests, you should rely on some asynchronous js form posting, for example with jQuery Form Plugin ( http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ )

Comment: Karl- The code is identical. I tried getting the control's unique id instead of the name, but it didn't get me any different results. I left the check in there in the event that I want to try a different name or id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to perform "window.close()" onClientClick, remove that client-side code. Perform a normal postback without "__doPostBack()" and inside of that server-side postback code send "window.close();" back to client via "ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript"

Comment: I tried  that approach with this line. It executes but does not close the window. 
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "cwin", "window.close();");

Comment: You have to pass one more parameter: `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "cwin", "window.close();", true);` - this will generate proper SCRIPT tags around JS code